Vite.Config Vue3 APP and C# / ASP.NET MVC. How to get the base vue directory correct and not update the URL?
I have a vue3 app that is rendered from a C# ASP.NET MVC controller.
The path looks like this:
mydomain.com/AutomatedDemo/{apikey}/{contactid}

This serves up the vue3 app using a vite.config.js and we have the following entry:
return {
      base: `/VueAutomatedDemo/dist/`,
      build: {
          sourcemap: true,
      },
      plugins: [
        vue(),
      ],
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
        }
      },
      
    }

This is because the source of the Vue3 lives under the VueAutomatedDemo/dist path. The app loads correctly, however once it does, it updates the URL to be:
mydomain.com/VueAutomatedDemo/dist/AutomatedDemo/{apikey}/{contactid}

The vue app loads and everything will run fine, but you cannot refresh, reload, or anything else because the URL path is wrong.
How do I tell vite.config.js that it needs to look in VueAutomatedDemo/dist for its source files, but leave the URL as / so that the ASP.NET MVC route stays correct?
mydomain.com/AutomatedDemo/{apikey}/{contactid}


play with root and base: https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html

@BorisMaslennikov are you saying root should be the "/VueAutomatedDemo/dist" and base should be "" or "./"?

I'm not sure it your case. but I know that you need to play with these 2 props
